# wget is working only when used with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, wget

I'm having quite a strange behavior with **wget** since yesterday.

I can download files by using **sudo wget**, but when I try the same file with only **wget**, I can get this error:

```
yusufh@ubuntu-yuh:~$ wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
--2010-12-17 09:34:11--  http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
Resolving www.kegel.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.kegel.com'
```

and with **sudo wget**:

```
yusufh@ubuntu-yuh:~$ sudo wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
--2010-12-17 09:35:37--  http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5865... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 190672 (186K) [text/plain]
Saving to: `winetricks'

100%[==================================================================================================>] 190,672     --.-K/s   in 0.03s   

2010-12-17 09:35:37 (6.92 MB/s) - `winetricks' saved [190672/190672]
```

After the comments below, here is an update:

I can use Google Chrome or Firefox perfectly without running it as root.

I use [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) to connect to the office proxy. So I need to use 127.0.0.1:5865 as the proxy for clients.

Result for env | grep -i proxy:

```
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local,
http_proxy=127.0.0.1:5865
ftp_proxy=127.0.0.1:5865
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:5865/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:5865/
https_proxy=127.0.0.1:5865
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local
```

while sudo env | grep -i proxy is empty!

HELP!

Comment: Are other programs able to resolve DNS names without being root?  If not, what are the permissions on the files used by the NSS (Name Service Switch) system, including /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to use Google chrome; that's about the only program that uses Internet without root.

Comment: I just ran into this problem on Ubuntu 16

Comment: Have you tried setting proxy for wget @TrevorSullivan ? Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346649/how-do-i-force-wget-to-use-a-proxy-server-without-modifying-system-files) or [this](https://www.unixmen.com/45713-2/).

Comment: @Yusuf Thanks -- I don't use a proxy though. It turned out to actually be a disk space issue, haha. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved.

It was in fact a bug with the **gnome-terminal** of Ubuntu 10.04.

I found my answer [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wget/+bug/232469).

In brief, just do a

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Then close the terminal and launch it again! Such a simple solution for such a big problem!! :D

That's why you should always keep you Ubuntu updated :P (I didn't want to upgrade because I wanted to test some other things first, and the Internet connection is quite slow here; but I think I'd better do it now!!)

Answer (score 3):

> Connecting to 127.0.0.1:5865...
>   connected. Proxy request sent,
>   awaiting response... 200 OK

What does it mean?

Hint: compare `env | grep -i proxy` with `sudo env | grep -i proxy`

Comment: nice pickup. I missed that at first glance.

Comment: I use ntlmaps to connect to the office proxy. So I need to use 127.0.0.1:5865 as the proxy for clients.  env | grep -i proxy gives NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local,
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865/
ftp_proxy=ftp://127.0.0.1:5865/
all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:5865/
ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:5865/
https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:5865/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,*.local,  while sudo env | grep -i proxy is empty!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I change My **nameserver** in `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Be careful with newer versions of Ubuntu though, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is overwritten on each restart. You can still add it through `/etc/network/interfaces` though.